# Activemq timeToLive from camel route not being applied until queue is visited

Tags: apache-camel, activemq-classic

We are configuring timeToLive for messages in a a queue using a camel route from a topic as follows:

```
<route errorHandlerRef="BrokerErrorHandlerEvents">
            <description>MQTT Events</description>
            <from uri="ourbroker:topic:events.>"/>
            <setHeader headerName="myUser">
                <simple>${headers.JMSXUserID}</simple>
            </setHeader>
            <setHeader headerName="myTopic">
                <simple>ssc.${headers.JMSDestination}</simple>
            </setHeader>
            <setHeader headerName="msgReceived">
                <simple>${headers.JMSTimestamp}</simple>
            </setHeader>
            <to uri="ourbroker:queue:ourqueue.ourbroker_events?
timeToLive=600000"/>
        </route>
```

Then we are sending a few test message from the ActiveMQ web interface. After the timeToLive (10 minutes), we expect the messages to go to the DLQ. The message stays in its queue after that time. Funny enough, if we visit the queue contents from the web interface all the messages seem to be "processed" and sent to the DLQ at this point of time (as if the checking was triggered by our visit).

Why is this just happening when we visit the queue from the web interface? Are we missing some configuration parameter to schedule the check of the expiration messages? (note: we have schedulerSupport="true" in the broker)

Comment: According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18507595/jms-topic-time-to-live) it would seem that the messages are only discarded if there is a consumer listening on the topic. Which could explain why the messages are only sent to the DLQ when you are actively looking in the topic.

Comment: We have a consumer for the queues. The consumer takes care of all the messages that are properly structured and brings back to the queue the ones that are not processed (our test messages). Our normal operations messages go through, and the other ones stay in the queue until we open it, and in this moment they go to the DLQ as they should as their time to live has expired. But... why just when we check it? Must it be a specific type of consumer?